# What is the name of the $(k-1)$ faces of a $k$ cell?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, terminology, cw-complexes

Is there an own name of the $(k-1)$ cells that are attached to a given $k$ cell (or in other words: of the $(k-1)$ cells that intersects a given closed $k$ cell, or yet another words: of the $(k-1)$ cells that are in the boundary of a given closed $k$ cell)?

Subquestion: Is there a notation for the relation beetween cells $A$ and $B$ that tells that $A$ is one less dimensional that $B$ and is attached to $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen *facet*, followed by *ridge* (k-2) and *peak* (k-3).

Comment: I  also remembered of these but momently don't find the resources. Could you please tell me, where are they defined by these words? (sorry, I forgot to add the reference request tag)

Comment: OK, I've found this [here](https://books.google.hu/books?id=xd25TXSSUcgC&pg=PA231&dq=%22vertices%22+%22edges%22+%22facets%27+%22ridges%22&hl=hu&sa=X&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBGoVChMI7ue6hfHXyAIVxcMUCh3J1Aur#v=onepage&q=%22vertices%22%20%22edges%22%20%22facets'%20%22ridges%22&f=false) (however this refers to polytopes and I wanted CW complexes, but this makes no difference.